# How to generate URLs to shared files in my google drive in batch? How about create Qualtrics surveys in batch?

Tags: batch, url, google-drive

I have about 200 images uploaded in my google drive, and I want their URLs. I can, of course, manually click "share" for each one of them to get their URLs then paste them in a text file myself, but I want to find a way to basically generate these URLs in batch. (would google drive API do the job? how?)

BTW, here's the reason why I asked this question:

I'm trying to generate surveys for Qualtrics in batch (using C++ to create a whole bunch of txt files and then import them to QUaltrics), and I have images embedded in each question for all my surveys. It would be a pain for me to go to google drive and get the URL for each and every image and insert them into my 200 some txt files. So yeah I really need to find a way to automatically do that.

I'm a total CS noob (my CS1 class just introduced OOP today!!), so my implementation probably seem unnecessarily convoluted and inefficient, but that's all I could come up with so far.

Feel free to suggest better approaches to this problem!